# Attempt to read property "name" on array

Tags: mysql, laravel, forms, model, sql-insert

**I am trying to enter data inside database table via form. I have created an instance of Model and accessed the columns of that table and assigned the input names of form but when I enter data an submit it says Attempt to read property "name" on array. Can anyone guide me if there is anything wrong.**

Code of Controller where im inserting datas to database

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    function registerUser(Request $req)
    {
        $data = $req->input();
       
        $user_model = new User;
        $user_model->fullname = $data->name;
        $user_model->mobile = $data->mobile;
        $user_model->email = $data->email;
        $user_model->password = $data->password;
        $user_model->save();

        return "registered successfully";
    }
}
```

Code of Form

```
<div class="register-form">
    <h4>Sign Up</h4>

    <form method="post" action="register">
        @csrf
    
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" size="40">
    
        <br>
    
        <input type="tel" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile number" size="40">
    
        <br>
    
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" size="40">
    
        <br>
    
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" size="40">
    
        <br>
    
        <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" placeholder="Sign Up" size="40">

        <hr>

        <p>Already, have an account <span href="#" id="sign-in-link">Log In</span></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function registerUser(Request $req)
{       
    $user_model = new User;
    $user_model->fullname = $req->name;
    $user_model->mobile = $req->mobile;
    $user_model->email = $req->email;
    $user_model->password = bcrypt($req->password); //laravel hashed password
    $user_model->save();
    return "registered successfully";
}
```

Comment: Always explain your answer. Apart from that, use the Laravel function to hash the password (`Hash::make($request->newPassword)`). Also, it could be the Model hashes the password by default using a mutator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`$req->input` is an array. Access it like so.

```
$user_model->fullname = $data['name'];
$user_model->mobile = $data['mobile'];
$user_model->email = $data['email'];
$user_model->password = $data['password'];
```

Comment: I personally prefer to use `$request->get('name')` to prevent undefined index errors. (also a little mistake `$data['name']` should be `$data['mobile']`)

Comment: In general i would never use this method, but felt it was apropiate in regards to the errors. I always end up $user->fill($request->validated); using fillable, setters and validation is the best approach imo